# .htaccess rewrite for a specific subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My goal:

every url http://www.domain.tld must be served by http://www.domain.tld/www/frontend/web 
AND
every url http://www.domain.tld/backend must be server by http://www.domain.tld/www/backend/web

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend
    RewriteRule ^backend(.*)$    /www/backend/web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$      /www/frontend/web/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

The first goal is ok, but the second no.

The server redirect my /backend to /www/frontend/web/backend/.

I tested even it using [an htaccess tester online](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it give me the same results.

For precision, even if i used [L], the first rewrite rule is ignored or, at minimum, the execution is not stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude rewritten backend URI from 2nd rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^backend/(.*)$ www/backend/web/$1 [L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|www/(backend|frontend)/) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/frontend/web/$1 [L]    
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why? Why the 'L' flag doesn't stop the rewrite flow? AND What is 'NC' ? It's not documented. i see [C] in the docs, but not [NC]

Comment: This works locally (XAMPP), but on production server it give me " forbidden You don't have permission to access /www/backend/web/ on this server."

Comment: `NC` is for ignore case comparison and `L` is for `Last`

Comment: sorry, was a my mistake (i temporary removed index.php to make some tryies), your reply is working at 100%! Actually I'm (the only man) able to install an Yii 2 advanced template on a shared host without changing directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a weird server configuration. After going through pretty much every other method of checking for SSL including but not exclusively:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
```

The only one that worked on the clients host was:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
```

Thanks to @anubhava for pointing me in the right direction. Hopefully this will save someone else wasting half a day of their lives.